# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php

Tags: php, html

i'm getting the following error

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php

everything else work fine... except for this !

Here's my query :

```
<?php

$inputuser = $_POST["user"];
$inputpass = $_POST["pass"];

$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "share";

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost:3306",$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or ("Database not found");

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username'= '$inputuser'";
$querypass = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'password'= '$inputpass'";

$result = mysql_query($query); 
$resultpass = mysql_query($querypass); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$rowpass = mysql_fetch_array($resultpass);

$serveruser = $row['user'];
$serverpass = $row['password'];

if ($serveruser && $serverpass) {
    if (!$result) {
       die ("Invalid Username/Password");

 }
        header('Location: Fail.php');
        mysql_close();


if ($inputpass == $serverpass) {

        header('Location: Home.php');

} else {


}
}

?>﻿
```

Comment: Kindly don't use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

Comment: @Kamal That duplicate doesn't help.

Comment: Use backtick in column and table name and your whole query inside quotes   `$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= '$inputuser'";
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated.**

You have an error in your SQL Syntax. Change your queries to this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= '$inputuser';
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password`= '$inputpass';
```

You must use backticks, `` ` `` and not `'` quotes.

And please try to combine them like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= '$inputuser' AND `password`= '$inputpass';
```

What if there are two users with the same password? You cannot expect all the users to use different passwords right?

Other things. You are passing the user input directly to the SQL. This is **very bad** and leads to **SQL Injection**. So you need to sanitize the inputs before you can send it to the Database server:

```
$inputuser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user"]);
$inputpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"]);
```

> Again, **do not use `mysql_*` functions.**

**Update the Code**

Use the following code.

```
// single query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$inputuser' AND `password`='$inputpass'";
// your original query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= '$inputuser'";
```

**Final Code**

```
<?php
    $inputuser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user"]);
    $inputpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "share";

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or ("Database not found");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= '$inputuser' AND `password`= '$inputpass'";

    $result = mysql_query($query); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        header('Location: Home.php');
        die();
    }
    else {
        header('Location: Fail.php');
        die ("Invalid Username/Password");
    }
?>
```

Comment: know its giving me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`' in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 13

Comment: @ChristepherArakelian Can you kindly put the full line here inside the comment? Just the code will do.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`' in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 13

Comment: @ChristepherArakelian I asked you to put the code. Full line of code.

Comment: yeah sorry here it is : $query = SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= '$inputuser';

Comment: Why haven't you wrapped it inside `"`? You did it correctly the first time.

Comment: now it worked but whenever i enter the right username and pass it still gives me the Failed login page

Comment: @ChristepherArakelian Which one did you try? Did it worked for you any time before?

Comment: @ChristepherArakelian See the edit in the question.

Comment: yeah it did... i did change the '' to `` it worked but on line 13 and 14

Comment: yeah how do i accept your answer ?

Comment: @ChristepherArakelian I have updated the final code for you. Kindly check it out.